# How to construct a space which is translation invariant but not rotation invariant

Tags: spacetime, group-theory, space, lie-algebra

I am just confused by the following idea.

Consider a 3-dimensional translation invariant space, we now have 3 translation generators. Then let us start with a point, the full 3-dimensional space should be generated by these 3 generators, namely by translating the single point in a 3-dimensional abstract parameter space.

But when we have a 3-dimensional translation and rotation invariant space, we can also generate the full space by translating a point. Since the 3 translation generators already generate a 3-dimensional space, what can the another 3 rotation generators do? 
Where is going wrong?

Put another way, could someone construct a space which is translation invariant but not rotation invariant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 3D cube with pacman topology is translationally invariant and not rotationally invariant. A space like this is a possible (but unlikely) flat space part of a cosmological spacetime